# Conic sections & eccentricity: known vertical hyperbola, find radius of corresponding circle?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

It is known that the eccentricity of a hyperbola is >1, and that of a circle is 0. These are both conic sections of (the lower nappe of) a (double) cone, with *r* the radius and *h* the height of the cone, and *theta* the angle of the intersecting plane to the vertical axis of the cone:

[image] (from [wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_conical_cones_of_conics.svg))

Assume the circle is a horizontal section of a plane with this theoretical cone, and the hyperbola a vertical section of a plane with the same cone. So these 2 planes are perpendicular, and assume these 2 planes intersect right in the point where the circle "touches" the outside of the cone (intersecting conics). In other words: the maximum of the (bottom part) of the vertical hyperbola touches the "left" side of the circle in 1 point. So it is a vertical hyperbola: both foci and midpoint lie on a vertical line (parallel to the Y-axis in a 2-dimensional plane).

[image]

Quick version: horizontal circle with unknown radius touches vertical hyperbola with known equation in a 3-dimensional space: can I know the radius of the circle using conic sections and eccentricity? Or some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewing a vertical hyperbola in a direction perpendicular to the cutting plane, the "edges" of the cone appear as the hyperbola's asymptotes.

[image]

Consequently, the diameter of the circle in question is simply how "wide" those asymptotes are at the level of the hyperbola's vertex. That is, if $A$ is a vertex of the hyperbola with center $O$, and $A^\prime$ is the point where the perpendicular to $\overline{OA}$ at $A$ meets an asymptote, then $|AA^\prime|$ is the radius of the circle. This distance is precisely the length of the *conjugate semi-axis*.

Writing $a$, $b$, $c$ for the transverse semi-axis, the conjugate semi-axis, and the distance from center to focus, and writing $e$ for the hyperbola's eccentricity, we know that 
$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \quad\to\quad b^2 = c^2 - a^2 = a^2\left(\frac{c^2}{a^2}-1\right) = a^2 \left(e^2-1\right)$$

So, the horizontal circle that meets a vertical hyperbola at its vertex has radius $b = a \sqrt{e^2-1}$. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

With the origin at the apex, the cone has the equation

$$\frac{z^2}{h^2}=\frac{x^2+y^2}{r^2}.$$

If you slice it with the vertical plane $y=a$, the hyperbola is

$$\frac{z^2}{h^2}=\frac{x^2+a^2}{r^2}$$ and the vertex is found at $x=0$,

$$z_{\text{vertex}}=\frac{ah}r.$$

For this point, the radius is $a$.